# Radio button: only check one button at a time

Tags: html, css

I'm using images like radiobuttons.
While I'm clicking on an image, the previous one remains still checked;
it becomes unchecked only when I stop clicking on the other.

Is there a way to make the others "unchecked" as soon as I click on one of them?

Thank you all.

```css
[type=radio] { 
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

[type=radio]:checked + img {
    border:2px solid blue; 
}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="trasl">    
    <img class="immaiuto" src="_Immagini/trasloco.jpg"/>
</label>
```

Comment: Should work if the radio buttons have the same `name` value

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/h5vp0y21/

Comment: maybe i was not so clear in my explanation: RADIOBUTTON MECHANISM WORKS; but I'd like to know if there is a way by which, as soon as I click on an image making it "checked", the others become IMMEDIATLY UNCHECKED; actually they remains "checked" until I remove my finger from mouse

Comment: "Click" and "mousedown" are not the same thing. You want the behavior to kick in **before** you release the left mouse button?

Comment: yes Chris, I'd like to obtain this

Answer (score 3):

Using the **same name on every radio button** and a different value works. Also each `input/img` pair must be in its own label.

```css
[type=radio] { 
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

[type=radio]:checked + img {
  border:2px solid blue; 
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="trasl">    
  <img class="immaiuto" src="https://loremflickr.com/50/50?random=2"/>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="tras2">    
  <img class="immaiuto" src="https://loremflickr.com/50/50?random=2"/>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="tras3">    
  <img class="immaiuto" src="https://loremflickr.com/50/50?random=3"/>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your `radio` buttons have the same `name` attribute. Also ensure that each radio button and img are wrapped in their own `label` tag, making it so that when you click on the image, your radio button also gets checked.

See working example below:

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

[type=radio]:checked+img {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="trasl">    
  <img class="immaiuto" src="https://remotive.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/stackoverflow-logo-remotive.png" alt="img1"/>
</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="trasl2">    
  <img class="immaiuto" src="https://remotive.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/stackoverflow-logo-remotive.png" alt="img2"/>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

## `<input id='radID' type='radio'>` & `<label for='radID'>`

1. Make sure all radio name attributes match. This makes a radio group share a mutually exclusive state (one is active and the others must be inactive.
2. Also, give the radios unique ids and pair them off with label that have corresponding `for` attributes that'll provide a larger striking area for users.
3. BTW if you don't want a jarring twitch from the buttons when you click them, replace the borders with outlines. Borders just like padding and margins take space but outlines don't.

---

### Demo

```css
[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto
}

[type=radio]:checked+label img {
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<input id='t1' name="test" type="radio" value="tras1">
<label for='t1'>
   <img class="immaiuto" src="https://www.caturanotraslochi.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Trasloco-pesante_2-1200x843.jpg"/>
</label>


<input id='t2' name="test" type="radio" value="tras2">
<label for='t2'>
   <img class="immaiuto" src="https://www.caturanotraslochi.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Trasloco-pesante_2-1200x843.jpg"/>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: solution was a jQuery:

```
$(".image").click(
     function() {
       $(".insert").stop().fadeTo( "slow" , 1, function() {
     });
});
```